# How do I answer this question during a test

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let v1 =\begin{bmatrix}
            1\\
            0 \\
            0
  \end{bmatrix}

, v2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 &\\
    1\\
    0
  \end{bmatrix}
, H ={\begin{bmatrix}
     s &\\
     s\\
     0
  \end{bmatrix}: s in R}. Then every vector in H is a linear combination of v1 and v2 because {\begin{bmatrix}
     s &\\
     s\\
     0
  \end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &\\
    0\\
    0
  \end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
    0 &\\
    1\\
    0
  \end{bmatrix}

Is {v1,v2} a basis for H?
I said that v1,v2 are not a basis for H because H only have one vector where v1 and v2 contain two set of vectors? how do I prove this in a test?

Comment: This question isn't *actually* on a test *right now*, right? So you wouldn't mind if I didn't answer this until a couple hours have passed, perhaps? =P

Comment: no it not, but the unit is going to be on the test next week. I wouldn't mind if you answered it

Comment: First check: are $v_1$ and $v_2$ actually in $H$?

Comment: You should at least show a bit of work...

Comment: H does not "only have one vector." The set H contains uncountably many vectors, because $s$ can be any real number. What you probably meant is that H is one-dimensional. (That is because there is a basis of it that has only *one* vector in it.) Also, "v1 and v2 contain two set of vectors" makes no sense. The set $\left\{v_1, v_2\right\}$ is a set that contains two vectors, but v1 and v2 themselves are not sets, so they don't contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

hint: To check if a set of vectors is a basis for the space defined by H, check that the vectors form a "coordinate system" for H. That is, every vector in H must be able to be formed from a linear combination of the vectors in the set {$v_1$, $v_2$} for the vectors to form a basis for H. Concretely, it might help to think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and how any point can be gotten by addition/scalar multiplication of the basis vectors [1,0] and [0,1]. Thinking about how you can prove this will point you in the right direction.

@TonyK: Yes, of course. Good catch. This isn't necessarily always obvious.

Comment: But that's not enough: the basis vectors must themselves belong to H.